# Would it be possible to discard the "How to format" DIV?

Tags: feature-request, editor

Hi,

I understand the importance of giving basic instructions on formatting, specially for non-technical users or beginners, but for some cases I find useful the ability of discarding or hiding this div box I mean.

To be more specific, I found this out when I resized the text area (feature of Chrome and some other browsers) in order to make easier to edit a large piece of code.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No -- because the *rendered post* will be a fixed width.

If you "optimize" your code for a larger width of a magically expanded edit box, that just means the final output will look terrible in the rendered post anyway.